# Why are the high-side and low-side outputs on this motor driver IC separate?

Tags: integrated-circuit, h-bridge

I'm trying to understand the datasheet for the VNH5050A motor driver. The pinout shows the high-side source (SOURCE HSx) and the low side drain (DRAIN LSx):
[image: VNH5050A pinout diagram]
but after that the datasheet refers to the outputs as OUTA and OUTB.
[image]
I assume that the high-side source is supposed to be connected to the low-side drain (as the block diagram shows), so my question is: **Why are they separate pins and not connected internally?**

UPDATE: Here's the datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00241540-1796943.pdf

Comment: So that you can connect something else between them? Does the datasheet (not linked in Q yet) show applications that don't connect them together?

Comment: why should they be connected internally? ... that would make the device less flexible

Comment: Yes, I agree with @jsotola that using separate pins make things more flexible.